# Compute for duration of every occurrence of a record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm stuck at my current task and have no clue how am I going to create a script on this particular scenario.

[image: Sample result set]

What I want is to compute for the duration of time between the records that has 'waiting for' value in it. Basically to compute how long it was in a 'waiting for' status.

Now the status can be changed all the time so I only need to total the amount of  duration in between these particular 'waiting for' status. (createtime highlighted in blue)

I haven't included any SQL script since the data is confidential, the below is actually a result already of my initial script that I created.

And what makes it more difficult is that I need to compute it for every ticket, so below example is only applied for ticket1. Other ticket numbers have their own total# of duration for 'waiting for'.

I am thinking to create a temporary table and assign a flag to identify these status occurrences, then loop at every results set of a specific ticket then store it in another resulting table.

If you have any suggestions or SQL features I could use, it would be great. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: We don't want a full SQL script anyway, a small reproducer is much better. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to come up with the following solution.  The basic idea is to self join your table such that the two records corresponding to a `Waiting for` group come together.  Then, we just take the difference of creation time between the two.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.Ticket, t1.[Create Time] AS wait_start, t2.[Create Time] AS wait_end,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.[Create Time] ORDER BY t2.[Create Time]) rn
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN yourTable t2
        ON t1.Ticket = t2.Ticket AND
           t1.[New Value] = 'Waiting for' AND
           t2.[Old Value] = 'Waiting for' AND
           t1.[Create Time] < t2.[Create Time]
)

SELECT
    Ticket,
    wait_start,
    wait_end,
    DATEDIFF(day, wait_start, wait_end) wait_in_days
FROM cte
WHERE rn=1
ORDER BY wait_start;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Anyone else who has a different query in mind is free to use my setup script.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one question, how do you ensure that the wait_start and wait_end are correct, i mean they are partnered correctly with its next record and not the other later record?

Comment: @WilmorHerald I don't do any such validation.  If an opening `Waiting for` is not closed in a way you consider properly, then my script would just pair it with the next closing (I think).  But do you expect this problem to occur in your table?

Comment: Yes there will be instances wherein the last record is in waiting for and there's no next record after that, what will be put as wait_end?

Comment: If the latest record is on 'waiting for', it should datediff on the current date(DATENOW)

Comment: I don't know what you want, but you should easily be able to adapt my script.

Comment: Yes, your script is more than enough actually.. Thanks Again. :)

Comment: Not at all sure why you didn't just use `LEAD()`? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=5cf7c824dc4879c06c6d832947e2de47